# Convert Numpy array to Pandas DataFrame column-wise (As Single Row)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array looking like this:

```
a = np.array([35,2,160,56,120,80,1,1,0,0,1])
```

Then I'm trying to transform that array into pandas dataframe with logic "one column-one value" like this:

```
columns=['age','gender','height',
     'weight','ap_hi','ap_lo',
     'cholesterol','gluc','smoke',
     'alco','active']

values = a

df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=columns)
```

This approach raises ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 11), indices imply (11, 11). What am I doing wrong and how to perform it in a right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
columns=['age','gender','height',
     'weight','ap_hi','ap_lo',
     'cholesterol','gluc','smoke',
     'alco','active']

a = np.array([35,2,160,56,120,80,1,1,0,0,1])

df = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(-1, len(a)),columns=columns)
print (df)
   age  gender  height  weight  ap_hi  ap_lo  cholesterol  gluc  smoke  alco  \
0   35       2     160      56    120     80            1     1      0     0   

   active  
0       1
```

If the reshape operation is not clear to read, a more explicit way of adding a dimension to the 1d array is to use [`numpy.atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html)

```
pd.DataFrame(np.atleast_2d(a), columns=columns)
```

Or simplier add `[]` (but slower if really many columns):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a],columns=columns)
print (df)
   age  gender  height  weight  ap_hi  ap_lo  cholesterol  gluc  smoke  alco  \
0   35       2     160      56    120     80            1     1      0     0   

   active  
0       1
```

Thanks Divakar for [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327069/creating-pandas-dataframe-from-numpy-array-row/45327097?noredirect=1#comment77615866_45327097):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a[None],columns=columns)
print (df)
   age  gender  height  weight  ap_hi  ap_lo  cholesterol  gluc  smoke  alco  \
0   35       2     160      56    120     80            1     1      0     0   

   active  
0       1
```

And another solution, thanks [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327069/creating-pandas-dataframe-from-numpy-array-row/45327097?noredirect=1#comment77618722_45327097):

```
pd.DataFrame([a], [0], columns)
```

Comment: Shorter one : `pd.DataFrame(a[None],columns=columns)`.

Comment: pd.DataFrame([a], [0], columns)

Answer (score 1):

Just reshape the array to what you need for the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

a = np.array([35,2,160,56,120,80,1,1,0,0,1])

columns=['age','gender','height',
 'weight','ap_hi','ap_lo',
 'cholesterol','gluc','smoke',
 'alco','active']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(a, (1,len(a))),columns=columns)
```